# How can I create column headers for my uicollectionview

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create headers on top of each column. Any advice or areas to review to achieve headers on the top? I was able to get 7 columns by doing some width division per cell to create days of the week (7 columns per row) but I want headers on top like a calendar to show s m t w t f s

I'm using a uicollectionview and want to basically create a month view.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be more than you want, or far too late, but take a look at: https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout

Comment: ah thanks Chris. I ended up getting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not the most elegant but my solution was this (tell me if this is OK??)

Create 7 labels in a separate view above the uicollectionview.

Set each label's width to be the uicollectionview width / 7

now add (programmatically) constraints for auto layout to each label with spacing between. How much spacing? This is dynamic based again upon the uicollectionview.

So something like this:

```
 "|-[Monday]-\(dynamicWidth)-[Tuesday]-(dynamicWidth)-[Wednesday-" etc etc.
```

As I did this, it actually worked and looked pretty good! Seems a bit hackish but worked for me.